# When exactly did General von Kluck learn of the French Sixth Army?

Tags: world-war-one, tactics

The French Sixth Army had been forming in Paris for some time before they positioned themselves to attack the German First Army under von Kluck. According to von Kluck's wikipedia:

> On 31 August Kluck turned his army southeast to support the Second
>   Army. In so doing, Kluck created a 30-mile gap in the German line
>   extending toward Bülow's stalled Second Army. Critically, the move
>   exposed Kluck's right flank in the direction of Paris where **(unknown
>   to Kluck)** General Michel-Joseph Maunoury's new Sixth Army was
>   deployed. The French learned of Kluck's change in course on September
>   3 thanks to reports from Allied aircraft, and this was independently
>   confirmed by radio intercepts.

*The Allure of Battle* by Cathal J. Nolan states:

> **On September 3rd, Moltke also realized that Joffre was massing to
>   counterattack north of Paris.** … The next day, the French attacked with
>   their scratch 6th army: bleu and feldgrau masses crashed into each
>   other in a corps vs. corps level fight 25 miles north of Paris. …
>   **Kluck had no idea** the new French 6th Army was there until the blow
>   landed.

And finally, from Maunoury's article:

> Sixth Army marched out from Paris on the morning of 5 September.[33]
>   Maunoury was to take up positions north-east of Meaux and was due to
>   attack the next day along the north bank of the Marne. Instead
>   **fighting began at 13:00 on 5 September,** in an area where French cavalry had encountered no Germans whilst scouting, but which had
>   since been occupied by German IV Reserve Corps, whose commander
>   decided to attack on his own initiative. During the night the Germans
>   withdrew to the east, but von Kluck, commander of German First Army,
>   shifted further forces up to face Maunoury's Army.

Does this mean that von Kluck first learned of the French Sixth at exactly 13:00, September 5th? It seems very odd that he had no idea an army was *right there* until the first blow landed. If Moltke had some idea the French were massing north of Paris, why was Kluck not also aware of this? Are there any letters, journal notes, orders, radio transcripts, or anything else that could pinpoint precisely when Kluck learned of the French Sixth?